# Get recordid on commnd button click

Tags: apex

I have a scenario where i have a class and a vf page. In the class i have a constructor and a save method. In this save method i need to get oppoid from url and validate it before saving.

The issue which i am facing is when i use `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')` in constructor i am able to get the oppoid but when i use it in save method i am not getting the id.

Note: I am not using any extensions controller

If i try like below i am getting the id.

```
public class recordid{ 

    public Id Aid {get;set;}
    public Id Aid1;

    public recordid(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        Account acc = new Account();
        Aid = controller.getId();
    }  

    public Account display(){

    Aid1= Aid;
    system.debug('1111111' + Aid1);
    return null; 

    }   


}


<apex:page standardcontroller="account" extensions="recordid">
{!Aid}
<apex:form>
<apex:commandButton action="{!display}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But what if the class is written like below - I am not getting the id if i write like this.

```
public class recordid{ 

    public Id Aid {get;set;}
    public Id Aid1;

    public recordid() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        Aid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }  

    public Account display(){

    Aid1= Aid;
    system.debug('1111111' + Aid1);
    return null; 

    }   


}
```

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this. Share some examples.

Comment: do you just want it to be written to the debug log?

Comment: Yes.. I am testing something

Comment: Are you passing the id in the URL. If yes, then Aid should receive the value in the constructor itself and should be available when the button is clicked.

Comment: In the url bar, after the Visualforce page name, make sure you add: `?id=###############`, where the number is a valid account id in your org.

Comment: I am reframing the question again.

Comment: Do not get set Aid variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can still use the standardController to get the Id but I think you should use it as a outside of the scope as variable..
 something like this should work :

```
public class recordid{ 
public ApexPages.StandardController std;
public Id Aid {get;set;}
public Id Aid1;

public recordid(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    Account acc = new Account();
    std = controller;
    Aid = std.getId();
}  

public Account display(){

Aid1= Aid; //OR Just std.getId();
system.debug('1111111' + Aid1);
return null; 

  }   
}
```